# Http calls are not working for ionic 3 IOS app. working fine in Android

Tags: ios, http, ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi i am developing ionic v3 app with Mobile first platform. app is working fine in android platform while using **https** with **domain** host**(https://domain/***) but in **Ios** device not able to call Https (https:domain.com/*) request. same time if we use direct IP address in the IOS device, we can able to connect our server APIs.

As a assesment purpose we used same APIS with domain in IOS native sample app, the application can able to reach the server. it is throwing only error in ionic v3 framework with IBM mobile First. please assist

```
> 2020-02-12 10:26:58.557400+0530 project[93862:8662691] THREAD WARNING:
> ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '243.088135' ms. Plugin should
> use a background thread. 2020-02-12 10:26:58.589840+0530
> project[93862:8662691] CDVWKWebViewEngine: handleStopScroll 2020-02-12
> 10:26:59.153539+0530 project[93862:8662691] WL_REQUEST 2020-02-12
> 10:27:11.172118+0530 project[93862:8662691] Could not signal service
> com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
> 2020-02-12 10:27:11.172654+0530 project[93862:8662691] Could not
> signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find
> specified service
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domainName/api/TestAPI/' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: The MFP server you are trying to connect to, is that a https endpoint? If so, is that a custom certificate?

Comment: It seems to be the CORS issue which is block HTTPS requests in Ionic. Can you share the list of installed plugins and its versions in that application. Also, please share the output of `ionic info`

Comment: what you mean by custom certificate. is it anything IOS certificate or server side. please advise.

Comment: cordova-open-native-settings 1.5.1 "Native settings"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.1 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"

Comment: cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-deviceinformation 2.0.2 "DeviceInformation"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"

Comment: cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2020012903 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2019121811 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.1.3 "NativeGeocoder"

Comment: cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.3.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
cordova-plugin-sms 1.0.5 "SMS"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"

Comment: cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.1 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"

Comment: ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.5 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)

Comment: Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Comment: cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0, ios 4.5.5

Comment: System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   ios-deploy        : 1.10.0
   NodeJS            : v10.13.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.3 Build version 10G8

Comment: nvironment:

   ANDROID_HOME : /Users/imgadmin/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the Fix. its very simple.

first build the app. In Xcode goto mfpclient.plist file remove the default port 443 and flash the app in to device. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs which you have provided, I suspect the issue is causing due to the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy [CORS].

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domainName/api/TestAPI/' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Try Enabling CORS in your server, it should resolve the issue which you are facing.

Here is the documentation to enable CORS for various servers.

- https://enable-cors.org/server.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_webcontainer_cors_config.html
- https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/193009/how-do-i-enable-cors-in-websphere-liberty-for-a-wa/

Comment: Hi I added content Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" in IHS after that i can able to access normal ionic app to connect or access reset API for MFP adapter but if we using  WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken and WLResourceRequest not established connection to server

Comment: normal MFP resource request not working in IOS. if we expose GET method of rest API for adapter to accessible in plain ionic v3

Comment: What response you are receiving in the callbacks of `obtainAccessToken` API ?

Comment: if we use MFP WL API to call the adapter service in ionic as well as normal cordova application which is download from IBM website giving below error,

Comment: - errorCode: 503
- errorMsg: "Request failed: service unavailable (503)"
- invocationContext: null
- responseHeaders: {Content-Length: "62", Connection: "close", Cache-Control: "no-cache,no-store", Pragma: "no-cache"}
- responseText: "<html><body><b>Http/1.1 Service Unavailable</b></body> </html>"
- status: 503